# Jquery display all subnav of parent

Tags: jquery, slide, nav

How can i display the parent's menu and display all the subnavs?
for example:
when i click first and will slide down those sub navs first-1 first-1-1 first-1-2......

As always, your assistance is appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/kg8x2ntv/

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">first</a>
            <ul class="nav-child">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">first-1</a>
                    <ul class="nav-child">
                        <li><a href="#">first-1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">first-1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">first-1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">2</a>
            <ul class="nav-child">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">first-1</a>
                    <ul class="nav-child">
                        <li><a href="#">2-1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2-1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2-1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <ul class="nav-child">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">first-1</a>
                    <ul class="nav-child">
                        <li><a href="#">3-1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3-1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3-1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Jquery:

```
function initMenu() {
    jQuery('.nav-child').hide(); // Start with nav-childs hidden
    jQuery('.nav > li.parent a').click(function() {
      var checkElement = jQuery(this).next();

      // When an `<a>` with a nav-child that isn't visible is clicked (tapped)...
      if ((checkElement.is('.nav-child')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            // Open the clicked (tapped) nav-child of `<a>`
            jQuery(this).addClass("active");
            checkElement.slideDown(165, 'linear');
            // Go to the other `<a>` elements of that nav-child scope and close them
            // (without closing nav-childs of other scopes, above or below)
            jQuery(this).parent().siblings("li").children("a").removeClass("active");
            jQuery(this).parent().siblings("li").children("a").next(".nav-child").slideUp(160, 'linear');
            return false;
      }

      if(jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
            checkElement.slideUp(160, 'linear');
      }
    });
  } // End initMenu()

initMenu();
```

i want the click first and the first-1 and children first-1-1 first-1-2...show in same time,and when i click first-1 or any subnav don't slideup,just click first it's can slideup all subnav.then,when i click anywhere outside the nav-child,all nav-child will slide up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like

```js
function initMenu() {
    jQuery('.nav-child').hide(); // Start with nav-childs hidden
    jQuery('.nav > li.parent a').click(function() {
      var checkElement = jQuery(this).next();
      var $uls = $(this).next().find('.nav-child').addBack().slideToggle(160, 'linear');
      $uls.prev('a').toggleClass('active');

      $(this).parent().siblings().find('.nav-child').slideUp(160, 'linear').prev().removeClass('active')
    });
  } // End initMenu()

initMenu();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">first</a>
      <ul class="nav-child">
        <li>
          <a href="#">first-1</a>
          <ul class="nav-child">
            <li><a href="#">first-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">first-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">first-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">first</a>
      <ul class="nav-child">
        <li>
          <a href="#">first-1</a>
          <ul class="nav-child">
            <li><a href="#">first-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">first-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">first-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: sir,could you help me check what's wrong with jsfiddle? when i click first menu again,slideup not working..http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/eruLu2po/

Comment: @John Sorry, probably I didn't explain it clear enough ,i want the click first and the first-1 and children first-1-1 first-1-2...show in same time,and when i click first-1 or any subnav don't slideup,just click first it's can slideup all subnav.then,when i click anywhere outside the nav-child,all nav-child will slide up, your example only have 2 level subnav,but i want 3 level subnav,correct jsfiddle update here:http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/eruLu2po/,and it's have a problem,when i click first again,slideup not working

Comment: @John but i want only click the "first" it's can slideup all subnav.in your code,when i click first-1-1-1,it's still slideup first-1-1-1-1 and others,btw,i found there are some html code error,i already correct it with your jquery code here:http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/eruLu2po/5/  ,appreciate for your patience!

Comment: @MotoTony so when you click on `first-1-1-1` what should happen? nothing should be rolled up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69654/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-mototony).

Comment: @Johny yes,nothing shoild be rolled up when i click any subnav,only main menu can slideup subnavs